# jQuery on/delegate correct syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

As the jQuery API is currently down, is anyone able to assist me with the below? I am ajax loading an unordered list into the web page and need to be able to attach hover and click events to the list items.

```
<ul>
  <li class="option">Item 1</li>
  <li class="option">Item 1</li>
  <li class="option">Item 1</li>
</ul>
```

So far I have tried a few variations of the below jQuery code using .on for version 1.7+

```
$("ul").on("click", "li .option", function(){
alert($(this).text());
});
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm aware that `.live` has been deprecated and that `.delegate` has been superseded so really only looking for a solution that will allow me to use `.on`.

Comment: No, it's not down. http://www.isup.me/http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: It was when I started writing this 30 mins ago, thanks for this pointless unhelpful comment.

Comment: Agreed; it was down for me earlier today. Not that it's entirely relevant right now.

Comment: Seems to me that @MattBall's comment was both pointed and helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not `li .option`, because it find element within `li` with class `option`, but you have this class to `li`, so it will be `li.option` or `.option`.

So for [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on), it looks like:

```
$("ul").on("click", "li.option", function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

But for [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate), it looks like:

```
$("ul").delegate("li.option", "click", function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

#### According to you edit

you're trying to bind `click` to `li.option` with container reference `ul`, which is also append to DOM alter. So you can go for `#content`, which already exists in DOM ans where you append you whole list.

So delegate event will looks like:

```
$("#content").delegate("ul > li.option", "click", function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with my ajax loaded content, when I click on the list items nothing happens.

Comment: @Kryptonite: Then something else might be wrong. thecodeparadox'  answer is correct.

Comment: @KryptoniteDove check my update, I think your problem will be solved.

Comment: @thecodeparadox thanks dude, managed to fit your delegate answer into .on! perfect thankyou again all!